# UI don't update after edit in "subview"

Tags: swift, swiftui

My data model is a class which contains an array of objects:

```
class InnerDataItem : Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var innerInfo = ""
    
    init(innerInfo: String = "") {
        self.innerInfo = innerInfo
    }
}

class MyDataModel : Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var info = "My String array"
    @Published var innerData: [InnerDataItem] = []

    init(info: String = "My String array", innerData: [InnerDataItem]) {
        self.info = info
        self.innerData = innerData
    }
}
```

I have a global var for an instance of the data model:

```
let modelData = MyDataModel(
    info: "Data model object",
    innerData: [
        InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "Inner info One"),
        InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "Inner info Two"),
        InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "Inner info Three"),
    ])
```

My ContentView shows a List of the inner data items. My model is passed to the ContentView from the app:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(dataModel: modelData)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: MyDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(dataModel.innerData) { innerItem in
                    NavigationLink {
                        InnerDataItemEditView(data: innerItem)
                    } label: {
                        Text(innerItem.innerInfo)
                    }
                }.onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                    dataModel.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                })
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

And the InnerDataItemEditView has a TextField where the value of the models inner items can be modified:

```
struct InnerDataItemEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: InnerDataItem
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Info: ", text: $data.innerInfo)
    }
}
```

When I edit the value of one of the InnerDataItem the data structure is updated with the new value, but the List (in ContentView) don't update to the new value. But if I use the Edit button to reorder the items in the list, after the move the updated value is shown. That is why I think the value is changed correctly by the TextField.

But why won't the UI update as expected?

I have tried various things, like passing a binding to InnerDataItemEditView, but I can't get it to compile :-O

Comment: You cannot "nest" `ObservableObject`s like this. Either make `InnerDataItem` a struct, or use `@Observable` instead.

Comment: Create a subview for the `label` so you can observe changes with `@ObservedObject var data: InnerDataItem`. `ObservableObject`s have to be observed at every level.

Comment: @loremipsum - thanks! That worked and was an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with your code. Here is an updated version
that works. The code uses a `@StateObject private var dataModel ...` in
your `TestApp` so that the view can observe the model throughout the view hierarchy.
Removed the `global var`.

The code also uses a `struct InnerDataItem` and bindings
in the `ForEach` loop and `InnerDataItemEditView` so that changes
can be made to your `innerInfo`. Also updated your `.onMove`.

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI
 
 @main
 struct TestApp: App {
     // --- here
     @StateObject private var dataModel = MyDataModel(
         info: "Data model object",
         innerData: [
             InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "Inner info One"),
             InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "Inner info Two"),
             InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "Inner info Three"),
         ])  
     
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             ContentView(dataModel: dataModel)  // <--- here
         }
     }
 }

struct InnerDataItem: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    var innerInfo = ""
    
    init(innerInfo: String = "") {
        self.innerInfo = innerInfo
    }
}

class MyDataModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var info = "My String array"
    @Published var innerData: [InnerDataItem] = []

    init(info: String = "My String array", innerData: [InnerDataItem]) {
        self.info = info
        self.innerData = innerData
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: MyDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach($dataModel.innerData) { $innerItem in  // <--- here, $
                    NavigationLink {
                        InnerDataItemEditView(data: $innerItem)  // <--- here
                    } label: {
                        Text(innerItem.innerInfo)
                    }
                }
                .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                    dataModel.innerData.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset) // <--- here
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}

struct InnerDataItemEditView: View {
    @Binding var data: InnerDataItem  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Info: ", text: $data.innerInfo)
    }
}
```

Have a look at this Apple link [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) for more info on how to manage data in your app.

Comment: Thank you for the code! I'll go for the solution @loremipsum suggested above. But I'll probably rework the data model in a while, so thanks for the documentation links too!